# Line Smoothing in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a 3 point line chart in Tableau with 5 series.  I would like to make the lines smoother instead of sharp angles.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Tried moving average- but not enough data points to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TabPy and interpolation to achieve smooth lines in Tableau:
https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000G54nZSAR/how-to-create-a-smoothed-line-chart-with-tableau-python-detailed-guide

[Curved vs Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3JOK.png)

Answer (score 0):

For a n-point line chart (for you n=3)

- Right click vizualiztion -> Trend lines -> Show trend lines
- Right click vizualiztion (again) -> Trend lines -> Edit trend lines
- In pop-up window select Polynomial, Degree with n - 1 (for you 2)
  degrees
- Click OK

Resulting trend line will be smooth and pass through all n points of your viz.

Now change vizualization type from line to circle (on a Marks shelf)